# [Unsupported ciphersuite][Java SSLSocket]

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I'm trying to connect a server through SSLSocket using protocol TLSv1.2. The server only supports the following ciphers.

- ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
- ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
- ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256

When I try to set enabled cipher suites, I'm facing following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ciphersuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.valueOf(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuiteList.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
```

I had tried to replace Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 8 from the following URL on C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\security But still unable to connect server.

**URL:** https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce8-downloads.html

I'm using the following Code to create SSLSocket:

```
protected void openSocket() throws IOException {
    LGR.info("Opening SSL socket to " + addr + ":" + port);
    String[] TLS_SUPPORTED_VERSIONS = new String[] { "TLSv1.2" };
    String[] CIPHER_SUITES = new String[] { "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256", "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256", "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256" };
    try {
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(addr, port);
        socket.setEnabledProtocols(TLS_SUPPORTED_VERSIONS);
        socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(CIPHER_SUITES);
        
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LGR.error("##Exception##", ex);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        LGR.error("##Throwable##", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use Use [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) instead of default JCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the supported cipher suites using:

```
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLContext.getDefault().getSocketFactory();
for (String cipherSuite : socketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites()) {
    System.out.println(cipherSuite);
}
```

The following entry matches your requested suite: `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`.

You no longer need the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files:

- in Java 8 u151/u152 the policy files were included in the standard Java distribution, but needed to be enabled explicitly: `Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");`
- since Java 8 u161+ (and in all upcoming Java versions), these policy files are included, and unlimited crypto policy enabled by default.

You can verify it as follows:
`Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES")` should return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` when unlimited strengh is enabled.

Comment: I didn't know that these ciphers are in OpenSSL and I have to use relevant IANA cipher. 
But now  I'm getting a "Connection reset" error. I have tried to enable debug and found the following lines.
Thread-8, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
Thread-8, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
Thread-8, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
Thread-8, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
Thread-8, called closeSocket()

Comment: When the TLS handshake fails (no mutually supported cipher suites between client and server, no mutual supported TLS version, or more likely: invalid X509 certificate), the connection will immediately be terminated. Connection reset by peer means the other end closed the connection. Debugging with OpenSSL, or in Java with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` may help in finding the cause.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Much appreciated.